# How do I check if tasklet_init call has failed?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, driver, kernel, kernel-module

Is there any way to check if the tasklet_init function which initializes a tasklet has failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you would see if you looked at the source (in `kernel/softirq.c`):

```
void tasklet_init(struct tasklet_struct *t,
                  void (*func)(unsigned long), unsigned long data)
{
        t->next = NULL;
        t->state = 0;
        atomic_set(&t->count, 0);
        t->func = func;
        t->data = data;
}
```

all the function does is set some structure members, so there is no possible way `tasklet_init` can fail.

In general if a kernel function returns `void` then you don't need to check if it succeeded or not.  And of course the nice thing about the Linux kernel is that you can always refer to the source and see if there are any ways something can fail.